# Mysql - Get all specific rows from one table matching criteria and relations if any from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table of 'product type attributes' which lists the names of all possible product attributes.

In another table I have the values for the particular attributes for a given product.

I need to query the database to get all attributes names for a specific product type and their values if they have any but also if they don't have a value assigned.

For example

Product type 1 : T-shirt 
Product type 2 : Poster

```
ATTRIBUTES

ID | PRODUCT_TYPE_ID | ATTRIBUTE NAME
1  | 1               | Size
2  | 1               | Colour
3  | 1               | Style
4  | 2               | Print Type
5  | 2               | Paper Type
6  | 2               | Paper Size
```

In the table 'product_attributes' that holds the values for these attributes (that also links it to a particular product) I have :

Product 1 : Men's T-shirt
Product 2 : Large Poster

```
PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES

ID | PRODUCT_ID | ATTRIBUTE_ID | VALUE
1  | 1          | 1            | Large
2  | 1          | 2            | Blue
3  | 1          | 3            | Mens
4  | 2          | 4            | Screen print
```

The result I want : 
Return all the attributes for a product type, even though 'print type' is the only attribute with an assigned value for that particular product.

```
ID | PRODUCT_ID | ATTRIBUTE_ID | ATTRIBUTE_NAME | VALUE
1  | 2          | 4            | Print type     | Screen print
2  | 2          | 5            | Paper type     |
3  | 2          | 6            | Paper size     |
```

I tried various JOINs but so far haven't got exactly what I want. The following returns values for other products not the specific one I need.

```
"SELECT 
 pa.value AS value,
 pa.product_id AS product_id,
 ptal.id AS attribute_id, 
 ptal.name AS attribute_name 
 FROM product_type_attribute_labels ptal
 LEFT OUTER JOIN product_attributes pa ON ptal.id = pa.product_type_attribute_id
 WHERE ptal.product_type_id = :ptid
 GROUP BY ptal.id"
```

Comment: Please add all your tables with some data, at this point I'm missing the labels and product tables.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have to this moment the following query can already provide some help

```
select a.id,pa.id,ATTRIBUTE_ID,`ATTRIBUTE NAME`,value from attributes a

join product_attributes pa on a.id=pa.ATTRIBUTE_ID

where product_id = 2
```

Change product_id accordingly

check this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bf33/9)